# Is attribute override inside lwrp action effectively of precedence level between 12 and 13?

Tags: chef-infra

I've been working with proprietary legacy cookbook, which has lwrp resource.
Its definition has such construct

```
action :someaction do
... 
    node.override['attr_group']['attr_a'] = 'some value' #Precedence 10?
...
end
```

Am i right in my assumption that setting an attribute this way effectively puts it in precedence level between 12 and 13 for later resources(suppresses role and env completely)?

I make such conclusion from the fact that role and env attributes are collected during compilation phase, but proposed example executes/sets new value during convergence phase.

[Node attributes precedence](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#attribute-precedence)

Update 1:
Let's consider the role set as

```
{
  "name": "myrole",
  "chef_type": "role",
  "json_class": "Chef::Role",
...
  "override_attributes": { #Precedence 11
    "attr_group": {
      "attr_a": "value from role"
    }
  }
}
```

What will be the value of node['attr_group']['attr_a'] seen by later resources after action :someaction executed?

Update 2:
Documentation on [node.debug_value](https://docs.chef.io/debug.html#debug-value) illustrates the layout of node data buckets, and clearly answers my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't generally refer to levels by those names, but this is the same thing as step 10 in that list. 9 and 10 are the same level though, just called `override`, but set at different times.